# ggplot2 not obeying set levels for categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels, factors

as the title states, ggplot2 is not obeying levels that I have set for a series of factors, such that when I plot the factors, they appear out of order. I have set the levels through

```
df$sites<-factor(df$sites, levels=c(..,..,etc))
```

and I have checked the dataframe through each round of subsetting to ensure that the levels have held, using

```
levels(df$sites_subset)
```

and I have even forced the levels after each subsetting as well. all told, I have about 27 factors before subsetting, and 17 in the final form where ggplot2 is not obeying the levels command.

the crazy thing is that the levels hold for certain plots that I have made, and not others. I've made about 30 plots of this type already using the same code, and this is the first time the levels have not held. has anyone else run into this type of issue? is there a stickier method for maintaining the levels? or alternatively, is there a way, other than using factor levels, to force ggplot to plot the x-axis in the order that I want?

Comment: If the issue is not replicable then I am not sure how to help. Seems like you know how to set the ordering already. Would it be possible for you to rename the levels in a way that ggplot uses to order factors by default. Add sequential numbers in front of your factor levels etc.

Comment: No one can help without a reproducible example.

Comment: hmm. the site names that i am using as factors have numbers which precede them (01_siteX,02_siteAB, etc), but are not the specific order i want them to be in, which may be confusing ggplot. it does seem like it is defaulting back to the alpha/numeric ordering. one thing that i have noticed is that after i set the levels, the factor converts from character back to numeric when i check with sapply(sites, mode). i work on some type of reproducible code. your suggestion to rename the levels is a good one- i may be able to create a new, alpha-numeric code and deal with the labels in a different way